# Citing multiple references in ACM template

Tags: citing

I used ACM [small standard format](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/acm-latex-style-guide), it seems when I have a citation like

```
\cite{ref1, ref2}
```

The second reference is not shown in the output and a question mark is shown in its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write them with no space

```
\cite{ref1,ref2}
```